# Electrical power in piezoelectric transducer

Tags: power, ultrasound, transducer, piezoelectricity

This question is from the book *Diagnostic Ultrasound Imaging: Inside Out
By Thomas L. Szabo*, regarding the power flowing into the piezoelectric ultrasound transducers.

In *chapter 5 (transducers) page*-*124*, it is mentioned that the total real electrical power flowing into the transducer for an applied voltage (V) and current (I) is:

$$W_E = II^*R_A/2 = I^2R_A/2$$

where current is: $$I = iωQ = iωC_0V$$.

The total transducer electrical impedance is given as: $$Z_T = Z_A+i(-1/ωC_0) = R_A + j(X_A -1/ωC_0)$$

where, $$Z_A: Radiation \ impedance\\ X_A: Imaginary \ part \ of \ radiaton \ impeadnce \ =  ωL \\ R_A: Real \ part \ of \ radiaton \ impeadnce $$

I am unable to understand why the power is given as: $$W_E = II^*R_A/2 = I^2R_A/2$$

why is I^2*R being divided by 2?

Comment: If the current is in fact a peak value then the RMS current will be \$\dfrac{I_{PK}}{\sqrt2}\$ and therefore power will be \$\dfrac{I^2_{PK}R}{2}\$

Comment: @Andyaka: you are correct.  Why are you not giving it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Guill there is no evidence that I can find that my comment is correct. There could be other reasons but only the op can confirm this.

Comment: @Andyaka I think the comment by you is the answer as I couldn't find anything anywhere else regarding this equation.

Comment: @radk do you want me to leave a formal answer that says the same as the comment?

Comment: Sure you can include this as an answer.